# guvcview can't capture video. Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: webcam, asus

Notebook PC | Asus N61DA | Ubuntu 12.10 | Built-In WebCam

In guvcview my webcam showing only half of image from up to down. The second half of image is black/blank from the middle of my screen to the bottom. Capture video in guvcview also impossible. Seems to be it'is recording something but when done, i'm running this video and there no sounds buy only animation like in windows media player some kind of screensaver.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also, if you go into your audio settings you can change which device uses the microphone.If you are using a webcam with a built in microphone be sure that it is selected in the audio settings. That ended up being my problem anyway, Hopefully that helps.